# Make Matplotlib widget background color match dark theme in Visual Studio Code

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter, ipywidgets

If I use a dark theme in Visual Studio Code and in Matplotlib, the figure can be configured to have dark background, but the background of the widget / cell is still white.

```python
%matplotlib widget

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('dark_background')

figure, axis = plt.subplots()

axis.plot(np.arange(100))
```

[image: Image of plot in Visual Studio Code]

This also happens if I use the option of the Jupyter extension to use the Visual Studio Code theme in the [notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) (actually, then it's even worse because the axis labels are not visible).

Note, that I need to use `%matplotlib widget` as a renderer, and cannot use `%matplotlib inline`. For inline, I found a configuration that works.

In the browser, it works if I select the Jupyter dark theme, so I guess, I would kind of select a different "theme" in the Jupyter renderer extension, if something like this is possible (?)

[image: Image of the plot in a browser]

Is there a way to configure the Jupyter extension / Visual Studio Code / ... to have a real "dark mode for Matplotlib"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-hacky solution is to add an html styling cell before your plot cell:

```html
%%html
<style>
.cell-output-ipywidget-background {
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
.jp-OutputArea-output {
   background-color: transparent;
}  
</style>
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9403

Comment: Thx! Note that the snippet needs to be used in conjuction with the code provided in my question, i.e. `%matplotlib widget` and `plt.style.use('dark_background')`. Thx for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

I have found a workaround!

(Make sure Visual Studio Code is closed.)

1. Open file explorer, go to:
   `C:\Users\<your_username_here>\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-<(THE VERSION NUMBER MAY VARY)2022.4.1021342353>\out\webviews\webview-side\ipywidgetsRenderer`
2. Open the **ipywidgetsRenderer.js** file (using [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) or [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) or even Visual Studio Code) before letting any Jupyter stuff run
3. Wherever you see `cell-output-ipywidget-background` followed by `background: white`, replace `white` with `black`.

Now the problem is solved. Enjoy :)

Comment: Doesn't this change the background colour regardless of theme?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you are right. But if you use a dark theme, It will prevent your eyes from getting burnt everytime you disaplay an image. It is just a workaround, not a Final solution. That will have to be implemented by the developers of Jupyter-VS-Code.

Comment: On MacOS ```ipywidgetsRenderer.js```can be found in the same equivalent path. Tested the workaround and it worked just fine. +1

Comment: For MacOS to be more specific I found the file at:
`/Users/$USER/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-<VERSION NUMBER>/out/webviews/webview-side/ipywidgetsRenderer/ipywidgetsRenderer.js`

I also set the alpha to zero instead so it doesn't matter what your theme color is:
`background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`