# Visual Studio Code Jupyter Notebook matplotlib WIDGETS OUTPUT CELL background colour change

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-widget

**LTDR:** I want the fourth image to look like the second image.

When using Visual Studio Code and Jupyter Notebook, if I use Matplotlib **widgets**, the colour of the **output cell** background is white.

This is very inconvenient. This issue is not present when using regular output(only when using widgets). I need to use widgets to give me interactive plots.

What settings should I change in order to make it work the way I want?

I have searched GitHub issues for the Visual Studio Code Jupyter extension, and I have searched Stack Exchange, but they do not deal with my issue. There are questions that deal with changing the cell colours, but I do not need to change the cell colours. I need to change the ****output cell background colour****. (Please see the last two images. I want to get rid of the white background.)

There is [a similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71206490/15065496), but *not exactly the same* and less detailed question that has also gone unanswered for a while now.

***When not using widgets, no changes to plt.style***

[image: NO_Widgets, White]

***When not using widgets, but background set to black by calling*** `plt.style.use("dark_background")`

[image: NO_Widgets_Black]

***When using widgets by calling***`%matplotlib widget` ***and no changes to plt.style***

[image: Widgets_White]

***When using both,*** `%matplotlib widget` ***and*** `plt.style.use("dark_background")`

[image: Widgets_Black]

- Jupyter extension version: v2022.4.1021342353
- Jupyter Notebook Renderers: v1.0.9

**Visual Studio Code Details:**

- Version: 1.67.2 (system setup)
- Commit: c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
- Date: 2022-05-17T18:15:52.058Z
- Electron: 17.4.1
- Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
- Node.js: 16.13.0
- V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
- OS: Windows NT x64 10.0.18363

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420533/make-it-mandatory-for-moderators-to-give-reason-for-deleting-a-valid-non-spam-a).